# I need to find out the name of a DDS Screen that a given telnet session is on? (I Series)

Tags: ibm-midrange, mainframe

I am looking for a program or API call that will give me, with absolute accuracy, the name of the Workstation Display File (and Its Record Type) that is being used by a given Job. I have the Job information (such as Job Name, Job User, and Job Number. This will allow me to quickly identify the Display File that a given job to assist in program development. If I can do this in RPGLE then I can share it over a SQL Connection to my interface/telnet program.

I have looked at using the Job List of Open Objects API (QDMLOPNF) and a combination of the Job Stack API (QWVRCSTK) but they do not give me the accuracy I need. They also assume that I know what DDS is attached to program, but if it is a system program or non standard program the results are not accurate.

Comment: It's "IBM i" these days.

Comment: It should be noted that most _system programs_ and many non-standard programs don't use DDS display files. They use either UIM panels or DSM output. The results can't be accurate for displays that are not developed in-house or developed by vendors that use DDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research and Google-ing I located an API that does exactly what I need it to. It's the Retriieve Output Information (QWSRTVOI) API and i found through an IBM API Documentation located here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/apis/wss.pdf.

Hope this helps anyone that was just as frustrated as me. IBM has to do it, so I knew there had to be an API to let me do it.

Comment: Was this the final answer?  There is currently an open bounty for this question.

Comment: Extraordinarily close to it with one or two problems, but yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this manually with the `DSPJOB OPTION(*OPNF)` command and look for open files of type DSP.

There is a job [API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qusrjobi.htm) available that may provide this information as well.

Comment: That wasn't the direct API, but it did point me in the right direction. I use this to pull up the job information and then QDMLOPNF to follow the user as a new screen is requested. Its fast, easy, and saves me time!

Comment: Not quite the answer. I just found out that it shows all DDS's that are active. I was assuming that the last one in the stack was active. However after some testing I found that not to be the case, and because we have multiple DDS with the same signature, I have no clue which one is directly active.

Comment: If the Job API does its not physical documented properly. I could not find a format that seemed to give me this information. Unless I'm missing another part or something.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered looking into IceBreak.  Should be very easy to do screen scraping with and present on a web page.  At one time there was talk about a free version.  http://www.icebreak.dk/

Comment: No, I need a way to get the DDS from telnet, I'm not looking to replace the solution I already have.